# Add up width of all links

Tags: jquery

I need to calculate the with of all links within one div.

```
var myWidth = 0;

$("#myDiv a").each(function() {
    myWidth = myWidth + $("#myDiv a").width();
});
```

The width I get does not appear to be accurate... Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#myDiv a").each(function() {
    myWidth += $(this).width(); // USE `this` WIDTH!
});
```

Or a different way to do the selection (just fyi):

```
$("a", "#myDiv").each(function() {
    myWidth += $(this).width(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$(this)` here which represents the current item in the `each` function iterations,    `$("#myDiv a").width()` will always give you width of first anchor in the div.

```
var myWidth = 0; 
$("#myDiv a").each(function() {
    myWidth = myWidth + $(this).width();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should get the width of `this` element (i.e. the current `<a>`):

```
var myWidth = 0;

$("#myDiv a").each(function() {
    myWidth = myWidth + $(this).width();
});
```